# Grails 3 with Quercus PHP

Tags: php, grails, quercus

I'm trying to integrate WordPress with grails 3. I used Quercus 4.0.39.

I'm new to grails and I don't know how to configure and how to run PHP file within grails app. Need detailed setup information. I tried grails PHP plugin, but the plugin is not available in the repo.

Comment: No, I don't have any idea. I'm failing in the integration itself. I need a complete procedure on how to integrate and run PHP using Quercus integrated with grails 3 app.

Comment: In fairness when I commented I was in review mode. I cannot help you in a technical level... but I have just googled `grails quercus wordpress`... This question is the 2nd result !!! The first result is a github repo with an issue for wordpress pointing [here](http://grails.org/plugin/php). I can only give you my advice: If you cannot find any information about what you are trying to do, (1) you either work in research and you are on the verge of great discovery or (2) you need to change the technology you are using (i know this is not always possible)...

Comment: I have created a Grails 3 version of the plugin, but haven't been able to upload it to the repository yet. Will try to make it available and post an answer with an example

Answer (score 0):

The sources of the Grails 3 Quercus PHP plugin can be found here:
[hbogaards/quercus-php-grails-plugin](https://github.com/hbogaards/quercus-php-grails-plugin/tree/grails3).

I have not yet been able to deploy a version to any repository, but if you build the plugin locally you should be able to use it. **Make sure you checkout the `grails3` branch.**

The plugin expects the PHP files under `src/main/webapp`

Hope this helps